# Is there a way to smooth a line between points such that the gradient at each point is 0?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to smooth this line between the points such that the line gradient at each point is 0 (as if there were a cubic function between the points, with each data-point as a turning point).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [8,2,1,7,5,5,8,1,9,5]

ax.plot(x,y)
```

'Unsmoothed' plot:
[image]

Comment: My advice would be "Don't do it". It simulates the presence of continuous data points that do not exist. Thanks to Excel, this data misrepresentation is popular but still a misrepresentation.

Comment: @Mr.T I wouldn't call a significant branch of mathematics that is interpolating a "misreprentation"

Comment: Exactly what I am talking about: `would be an aesthetic choice`. It looks cute and round, and I don't get an error message, so it must be correct. I cannot tell you how many academic papers I see based on this thinking.

Comment: @matszwecja Interpolation has underlying model assumptions. "It looks aesthetically pleasing" is not a model.

Comment: I have to say I join @Mr.T on the fact that smoothing **scientific data** for aesthetics shouldn't be done. That said, programming curves can also be done for artistic purposes or anything else and I'd rather leave the potential "ethical" decision whether or not to smooth to the user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if the use case is desirable, but you can use a spline interpolation with [`scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

cs = CubicSpline(x, y)
xs = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num=100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, label='data', marker='o')
ax.plot(xs, cs(xs), label='spline')
ax.legend()
```

output:

[image: spline interpolation]

##### alternative: [`CubicHermiteSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicHermiteSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.CubicHermiteSpline)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import CubicHermiteSpline

cs = CubicHermiteSpline(x, y, np.zeros(len(x))) # force gradient to zero
xs = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num=100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, label='data', marker='o')
ax.plot(xs, cs(xs), label='spline')
ax.legend()
```

[image: cubic hermite spline]

###### with threshold (only for "nice" display purposes)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import CubicHermiteSpline

g = np.gradient(y)/np.gradient(x)
g = np.where(abs(g)>2, g, 0)

cs = CubicHermiteSpline(x, y, g)

xs = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num=100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, label='data', marker='o')
ax.plot(xs, cs(xs), label='spline')
ax.legend()
```

output:

[image: custom spline]

Comment: Thanks - this isn't quote what I'm looking for. The datapoints need to be the turning points for the curve. I feel like the CubicSpline function could work if it were possible to plot between each two consecutive points to form the cubic line.

Comment: @Andy check the alternative, a CubicHermiteSpline might better suit your needs, if not please provide a schematic + better description of your needs

Comment: @Andy note that if you have a linear stretch (e.g., 1,2,3,7,10), forcing a 0 gradient will give a staircase like look ;)

Comment: @Andy I added a third alternative to avoid the staircase like display (with a threshold, here gradient of 2), note the difference on point #2 and the extremities